# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens: SELECT 1 AS expression

Tags: database

Good Morning

I get this error: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens: SELECT 1 AS expression (edited)

I need to insert an array of values into a field in the table using merge

I attach my code for revision. Thank you

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$this->nids=array();
/**
* Load the current User.
* Use \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load.
*/
$uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
$this->nids= $form_state->getValue('field_nodes');

// foreach ($this->nids as $nid){
//   $this->nid = $nid;
//   // var_dump($this->nid); die();
// }

  $result = $connection->merge('WishList')
  ->key(['nid' => $this->nids])
  ->fields([
  'uid' => $uid,
  'nid' =>$this->nids,
  ])->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to insert an array of values into a field in the table using merge

If you mean that literally, it isn't possible - a PHP array is not a type of data that can be inserted into MySQL.

Maybe you meant to loop over the IDs instead:

```
foreach ($this->nids as $nid) {
  $result = $connection->merge('WishList')
    ->key(['nid' => $nid])
    ->fields([
      'uid' => $uid,
      'nid' => $nid,
    ])->execute();

}
```